# C# ironOCR to recognize single number

Tags: c#, ocr

I am trying to use IronOCR to recognize japanese.

When it comes to single numbers like `1`, `3` , and `7` it does not work. Numbers like `5,920` or any longer numbers than single digit will show correctly.

I have read some related articles here.

Suggestions like `Ocr.Configuration.PageSegmentationMode=TesseractPageSegmentationMode.SingleChar;` are not available.

I can not be sure there is always single or not single digit.

Here is my code and what should i do ?

```
using (var Input = new OcrInput(croppedImage))
{
    Input.DeNoise();
    Input.Invert();
    //Input.DeepCleanBackgroundNoise();
    var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
    textBox1.Text = Result.Text;
    //Result.SaveAsTextFile("JapaneseText.txt");
}
```

Working number

[image: Image showing the text "29,600"]

Not working number

[image: Image showing the text "2"]

Comment: Can you provide us with images that work and some that don't so that we can test? Also can you make sure the code is a [mcve] for testing purposes? That's full code and steps to set up and run so that we can see the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried download the Financial package and trying it again with the following code?

```
PM> Install-Package IronOCR.Languages.Financial
```

You can read about it here, it is supposed to help you recognize numbers. https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/languages/financial/

Below is the code I tried with a single number and it worked for me.

```
var ocr = new IronTesseract();
ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.Financial;
ocr.Configuration.PageSegmentationMode = TesseractPageSegmentationMode.SingleChar;
```

You can also whitelist it to do only numbers which might help out.

```
ocr.Configuration.WhiteListCharacters = "0123456789";
```